# Trying to extract the configuration file (XML, DLL, DMX, etc) to save them and overwrite them when needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this code to extract the config file to make a back up in case the modification we made don't work. But when I run it nothing happen. It doesn't even ask me ("Do you want to do an Extraction, a Recovery, or erase the safety backup").

Sorry if it is obvious but I am quite new to codding.

Thank you for your help.

#### Edit:

This is the new code that is working but that only walks through the current directory, I can't make it walk through the directory tree yet.

#### This is the new code

```
import os
import pickle
import shutil
choice = input("Do you want to do an Extraction, a Recovery ")  #do you want 
to an ###extraction or a ###recovery    

addfiletype = 'm'

backuptemp = []
savedpath = os.getcwd()

if os.path.isdir("./configbackup/") == False:
os.makedirs("./configbackup/")  

if choice.strip()[0].lower() == 'e':
    filetype = ['xml', 'dll', 'dmx', 'lua', 'config', 'cfg']
    print(filetype)
    addfiletypechoice = input("Do you want more filetype? Y/N ")
    if addfiletypechoice.strip()[0].lower() == 'n':
        pass
    elif addfiletypechoice.strip()[0].lower() == 'y':
        addfiletype = input("Which filetype do you want to add? To stop 
write no ")
        while addfiletype != addfiletype.strip()[0].lower() != 'n':
            addfiletype = input("Which filetype do you want to add? To stop 
write no ")
            filetype1 = filetype.append(addfiletype)
            print(filetype1)
    else:
        print("Choose between yes and no")
    filetypetuple = tuple(filetype)
    print("Backing up files")
    for filename in os.listdir("./"):#walk in files iterate through 
(filetype)
        if filename.endswith(filetypetuple):
            f = open(filename, 'r')
            filepath = os.getcwd()
            content = f.read()
            f.close()
            backuptemp.append([filepath, filename, content])
            print(".")
            continue
        else:
            continue
    os.chdir("./configbackup/")
    pickle.dump( backuptemp, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
    print("Extraction completed")                
elif choice.strip()[0].lower() == 'r':
    os.chdir("./configbackup/")
    backuptemp = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
    for list in backuptemp:
        os.chdir(list[0])
        file = open(list[1], 'w') #filename.type
        file.write(list[2]) #write content to file
        file.close() #close(list[1])
        print(".")
        continue
    print("Backup retrieved")

else:
    print("Please choose between extraction and recovery")  
input("Press any key to exit")
os._exit(0)
```

---

#### This is the old code

```
import os
import pickle
choice = input("Do you want to do an Extraction, a Recovery, or erase the safety backup")   #do you want to an ###extraction or a ###recovery   
filetype = ['xml', 'dll', 'dmx', 'lua', 'config']
backuptemp = []
savedpath = os.getcwd()
if os.path.dirname(.\\configbackup\\) == true:
else: 
    os.makedirs(".\\configbackup\\")
if choice == "extraction" or "Extraction" or "e" or "E":    #if ### extraction or E
    print "Backing %(filetype)d" %{"filetype": filetype} 
    for filename in os.listdir(.\\*\\):#walk in files iterate through (filetype)
        if filename.endswith(filetype)
            content = os.open(filename)
            backuptemp.append([os.getcwd, filename, content])#write path in \\configbackup\\txtfiledate.txt+"\n" or pickle backuptemp.append()
            print(backuptemp)### append file content !! will it make a max char error??
            os.close(filename)
            continue
        else:
            continue
    os.chdir(.\\configbackup\\)
    pickle.dump( backuptemp, open( "save.p", "wb" ))    

elif == "recovery" or "Recovery" or "r" or "R":
    i = 0
    for i < len(backuptemp):
        os.chdir(backuptemp[i][0]) #directory
        os.open(backuptemp[i][1]) #filename.type
        os.write(backuptemp[i][2]) #write content to file
        os.close(backuptemp[i][1])
        print ("Backup retrieved")

else:
    print("Please choose between extraction and recovery")
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This line produces a syntax error:

```
if os.path.dirname(.\\configbackup\\) == true:
```

Until you fix that your code will never run so will never produce any output.

This is the doco for `os.path.dirname`:

> os.path.dirname(path)
>   Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split().

What is your line attempting to do in that context?

- What is `true` trying to do in that context?
- Do you mean `True`?

  - If so then how do you intend the directory name returned by `os.path.dirname` compared to `True` to achieve?

What is it, in detail, that you are trying to achieve here?

---

A couple of other things to look at. There is a lot more needing work in your code but here's a couple of things to look at now.

---

This is bad style:

```
if os.path.dirname(.\\configbackup\\) == true:
else:
```

Prefer this:

```
if os.path.dirname(.\\configbackup\\) == true:
    pass
else:
```

---

This line is a clumsy and difficult way to test the user input:

```
if choice == "extraction" or "Extraction" or "e" or "E":
```

Instead just test the first, non-whitespace character of the input in a known case. Like this:

```
if choice.strip()[0].lower() == 'e':
```

Running left to right we are:

- removing any whitespace from the head and tail of the input string, then
- extracting the first character from the remaining string, and
- forcing that character to lowercase, and
- testing if that first, non-whitespace, lowercase character is 'e'.

This will not work nicely if the input is an empty string but dealing with that is something for another learning stage in your journey.

---

Where's the closing colon for this line?

```
if filename.endswith(filetype)
```

---

Comment: It still doesn't work but I am going the right way.
I was wrong with os.dirname and needed os.path.isdir to test if it existed, I made those changes too.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want some more help update your question with the new code and add a comment that you have done so. If you feel you are on your way either accept an answer or delete your question so people know that the original is no longer the current issue.